# Allow user to delete own account

Tags: users

In *admin/people/permissions* I checked the boxes next to the "Cancel own user account" and "Select method for canceling own account" but in the user profile (*user/NID/edit*) the **Cancel account** button is not present.
Why? What could I have forgotten?

I have assigned the right role.

Thank You.

Comment: By default the user only has to have that cancel permission to cancel their own account or administer users to cancel other peoples accounts. If you have profile 2 module or similar installed then the cancel button will only appear on the main account page, not other profile pages. Do you have any other user permission related modules installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure you are not using user 1, because you can't cancel user 1.
- Clear caches after changing permissions.

Update:
Check for any modules you have which may affect Permissions.
In this case Administer Users by Role may be lacking some permissions that you need to set.

Comment: I not using user 1, I have created a new user with a new role.

Comment: So let's say you have user2 with the role 'admin'.
'admin' has "Cancel own user account" and "Select method for canceling own account" checked?
Did you clear cache?

Comment: I created a new role named editor. Created a new account and assign editor as role. Assigned at editor the permissions: "Cancel own user account" and "Select method for canceling own account"
But this user can't cancel the account. The button "Cancel account" is not present.

Comment: Ok I followed your process step by step on my sandbox vanilla D7 install and can still see the Cancel account.  Do you have any other modules set up that affects permissions?

Comment: Administer Users by Role, Field Permissions, Role Assign, Profile2

Comment: Administer Users by Role may be affecting cancellation. Is this permission checked for the editor role? Cancel users with role editor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35888/discussion-between-japo-domingo-and-kb8).

Comment: Damned, you're right!

Comment: updated answer.